# Callback File System: eldos.cbfs.ECBFSError: Access is denied

Tags: java, windows, callback, filesystems, fuse

I've requested trial license for [Callback File System](https://www.eldos.com/cbfs/) and tried to write simple application using java! So, I've written next few lines and run it and received exception `eldos.cbfs.ECBFSError: Access is denied`

Code

```
    import eldos.cbfs.CallbackFileSystem;
    import eldos.cbfs.ECBFSError;
    import eldos.cbfs.boolRef;
    
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    
    /**
     * @author Sergii.Zagriichuk
     */
    public class Test1 {
        private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test1.class.getName());
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            CallbackFileSystem callbackFileSystem = new CallbackFileSystem();
            callbackFileSystem.setRegistrationKey("My registration key ");
            try {
callbackFileSystem.install("<path to cab>\\cbfs.cab", "Test", true, 131072, new boolRef(false));
            } catch (ECBFSError ecbfsError) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ecbfsError.getMessage(), ecbfsError);
            }
        }
    }
```

What do I should to do for fix this problem?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow is the right place to ask for CBFS support. I've provided you a link to our support options in the e-mail I sent you.